# UISearchBar custom class and apparance

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ios7

I am totally new to iOS development and I need help with customizing UISearchBar appearance.

Here is what I'm trying to do

[image]

First of all, how to get rid of that surrounding grey bar and then how to change background of white textfield.

Also, I made a new class that extends UISearchBar and apply it to search bar but I don't know which method to call for initialisation of it, like

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {}
```

in ViewController class. Where to put my custom code in UISearchBar class.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a search bar with some options fleshed out, change some of these values to tweak it how you want it, use this like a template if you will:

```
    UISearchBar * _searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] init];
    [_searchBar setPlaceholder:@"Search..."];
    [_searchBar setTranslucent:TRUE];
    [_searchBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleDefault];
    [_searchBar setSearchBarStyle:UISearchBarStyleProminent];
    [_searchBar setDelegate:self];
    [_searchBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [_searchBar setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [_searchBar.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor clearColor].CGColor];
    [_searchBar setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:FALSE];
    [_searchBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new]];
    [_searchBar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

    [[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setDefaultTextAttributes:@{
                                                                                                 NSFontAttributeName:fontMagicForRegularNSHFont,
                                                                                                 NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor purpleColor]
                                                                                                 }];

    [[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setTitleTextAttributes:@{
                                                                                                   NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor purpleColor]
                                                                                                   } forState:UIControlStateNormal];


    [[UISearchBar appearance] setSearchFieldBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"text_box"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"searchy"];
    [[UIImageView appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height)];

    [[UISearchBar appearance] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"exitred"] forSearchBarIcon:UISearchBarIconClear state:UIControlStateNormal];
    [[UISearchBar appearance] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"exitred"] forSearchBarIcon:UISearchBarIconClear state:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [[UISearchBar appearance] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"searchy"] forSearchBarIcon:UISearchBarIconSearch state:UIControlStateNormal];
    [[UISearchBar appearance] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"searchy"] forSearchBarIcon:UISearchBarIconSearch state:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Here's the answer to your second question:

```
    [[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];
```

Don't iterate through subViews that's an ignorant method to use when Apple freely gives you the power to use their API to change the color of the background of UITextField using UIKit. You'll see that most answers here on stack for this same sort of thing claim to use the iteration through subViews, but these are failure answers, and another reason why StackOverflow is mostly full of useless trash.

Also, here's from the Apple Docs, in fact from the header file of UIAppearance.h

/* To customize the appearances for instances of a class contained within an instance of a container class, or instances in a hierarchy, use +appearanceWhenContainedIn: for the appropriate appearance proxy. For example:

```
 [[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISplitViewController class], nil] setBarTintColor:myColor];
 [[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UITabBarController class], [UISplitViewController class], nil] setBarTintColor:myTabbedNavBarColor];
```

*/

Hope this helps, in fact, it will help, you will not really have to worry about customization again if you follow the instructions above, everything will then become super easy mode. Good luck!

Gist action:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b38bfd23130981d02bca

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2358875a896895df3e5b

to use a sub class like this, you have to create a UIViewController without StoryBaord, and then do this:

CCCUSTHomeViewController.m

```
#import "EXAMPSubViewWithSearchBar.h"
#import "CCCUSTHomeViewController.h"

@interface CCCUSTHomeViewController () 
@end

@implementation CCCUSTHomeViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self)
    {

    }
    return self;
}

-(void)loadView 
{
    [self setView:[EXAMPSubViewWithSearchBar new]];
}

-(EXAMPSubViewWithSearchBar*)contentView 
{
    return (id)[self view];
}
@end
```

and then this for the header of the UIViewController:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CCCUSTHomeViewController : UIViewController
@end
```

Comment: Do you have a full example anywhere? (e.g. Github). I'd love to see what this looks like fully implemented.

Comment: I do, but unfortunately, all of my code  very much locked down due to what it includes and who I work for, so, let me see if I can sniff out something simple using this, and then drop it into a Gist.

Comment: Here you go, MendyK gist here : https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2358875a896895df3e5b    and here:   https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b38bfd23130981d02bca  this is a subclassed UIView with the UISearch bar inside it, to test it out, I'll post what you must do in my answer above

Answer (score 1):

1. To get rid of surrounding grey bar, change the searchBarStyle of UISearchBar to UISearchBarStyleMinimal.
2. To change the background of text field of search bar: Iterate on subviews of UISearchBar and check if the subview is of type UITextField, if yes, store reference of it in a variable and change the background of UITextField with desired color.

Comment: First one did a trick. But where to put second iteration code in custom class, in which method of CustomSearchBar : UISearchBar class?

Comment: It is not required to do in CustomSearchBar class, you can do that in class which is using CustomSearchBar but if you want to do it in CustomSearchBar class then you override layoutSubviews method. but in layoutSubviews method remember to do this only for the first time as layoutSubviews will be called multiple times